Was there ever a protocol to send profanity censorship tones out-of-band over television, so that viewers could turn them off? If not, why not?
These days, in the Western world, closed captioning is delivered out-of-band, so the captions are not actually part of the video itself, allowing viewers to turn them off if they are not desired (although in China, they are usually delivered in-band and burned into the video itself). However, around the world, the "bleep" sound used to censor swearing is usually part of the audio track itself. The other day, I decided to write down this random idea that I originally had in elementary school of an out-of-band profanity censoring protocol (I'm in my third year of university now, but I'm studying software engineering, not electronic or communications engineering): https://www.felixan.ca/files/opcp.pdf Was there ever a protocol to send profanity censorship tones out-of-band over television, so that viewers could turn them off? If not, why not?
If I ever have time and if this protocol doesn't exist, I want to try to make my own device one day that could encode and decode such a signal and test it on the amateur radio bands (I am a licensed ham radio operator, and fast-scan TV is one of the modes you can use).

yes. for example
"TV guardian" uses the OOB  closed caption data and a build-in dictionary to censor "bad" words.
All the data is present in the composite video signal, so it may not be necessary to actually generate a modulated RF carrier

I'm aware of the TV Guardian, but it was not ideal, since the entire sentence would be muted, and censorship couldn't be customized by the broadcaster. But thanks anyways for the answer!
